# Has $p$-schatten pooling been done in CNN in deep neural networks?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, machine-learning, convolution, computational-mathematics

In the latest 10 or so years developments in deep neural networks Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)s have been very popular. In these networks there is a specific procedure called [pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#Pooling_layer), which this question relates to.

Given that both Max-pooling and Average-pooling seem to be used in CNNs and the fact that the $p$-schatten norms have a max-approximating behaviour as $p$ grows without bounds:

$$\lim_{p\to \infty}\|v\|_p = \lim_{p\to \infty}\left\{\left({v_1}^p+\cdots+ {v_n}^p\right)^{1/p}\right\} \to \max(v)$$

I was wondering if any kind of $p$-schatten pooling has been tried as something of a smoother variant of max-pooling.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Yes every obvious kind of layers have been tried. Also the goal of neural networks is to optimize the weights, there are obvious modifications of the pooling function including some weights/parameters to optimize.

Comment: You may wish to post in https://stackoverflow.com/ as well, since I believe a lot of applied machine learning topics are addressed there.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @ad2004 Yeah.. I would, but there is some mod on stack-overflow who doesn't really like me.